# Deploy DB to azure from VS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-sql-database

I have MVC5 project (web role and azure service ) which is working against local DB V11.0 and working fine,There is a way to create some script in the MVC(web role) or other place in the project which will create the DB automatically in azure ,Currelntly I have change the connection string to work with azure DB which I created manually in azure portal .
if there is option please provide the steps and example...

Thanks,
Jhon

This is the SQL which created the azure & local DB

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Config] (
    [ID]    INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]        NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Email]        NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is exactly, but take a look at MSDN site (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh420322.aspx#SQLAzure). Step 6 has useful information for how to use web.config in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, create a Database project in your Solution. Then you compare local DB to your cloud DB or just publish the project and it will create tables, views, etc.

Comment: Thanks,But how should I do that can you please provide step by step example ?

Comment: @JohnJerrby http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/245612/Creating-a-Database-Project-with-Visual-Studio http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2013/01/28/using-visual-studio-database-projects-in-real-life.aspx